# jQuery and colorbox “is not a function”

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This is strange. I have thouroghly searched for an answer, the funny thing is I have another page on this site that colorbox is working.

Relevant header code:

```
<script src="colorbox/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/example5/colorbox.css" />

<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="Javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".lightbox").colorbox({width:"700px", height:"500px", iframe:true, opacity:.65});
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the error on the $(".lightbox").colorbox statement.

Comment: Example is at http://www.crossroadsoflearning.com/staging/overview.php

Comment: Working page is http://www.crossroadsoflearning.com/staging/catalog-lcw.php

Answer (score 2):

You have jquery included twice on the page that fails.  Versions 1.10.2.min and 1.9.0.min.  1.10.2.min is the only one included on the page that works.  Multiple versions of jquery mess all sorts of stuff up.

This is the guy giving you trouble:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="nivo/demo/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox'
```

Did you include the colorbox library?